# Best way to categorize products in rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, categorization

So, I'm trying to create a product categorization 'system' in my rails 4 app.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations
  has_many :categorizations
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers

  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  has_many :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Also, what gem should I use? (awesome_nested_set, has_ancestry)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in one of my projects which is live right now and works very well.

First the category model, it has a name attribute and I am using a gem `acts_as_tree` so that categories can have sub categories.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree order: :name
  has_many :categoricals
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
end
```

Then we will add something called a `categorical` model which is a link between any entity(products) that is `categorizable` and the `category`. Note here, that the `categorizable` is polymorphic.

```
class Categorical < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true

  validates_presence_of :category, :categorizable
end
```

Now once we have both of these models set up we will add a concern that can make any entity `categorizable` in nature, be it products, users, etc.

```
module Categorizable 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :categoricals, as: :categorizable
    has_many :categories, through: :categoricals
  end

  def add_to_category(category)
    self.categoricals.create(category: category)
  end

  def remove_from_category(category)
    self.categoricals.find_by(category: category).maybe.destroy
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end
end
```

Now we just include it in a model to make it categorizable.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Categorizable
end
```

The usage would be something like this

```
p = Product.find(1000) # returns a product, Ferrari
c = Category.find_by(name: 'car') # returns the category car

p.add_to_category(c) # associate each other
p.categories # will return all the categories the product belongs to
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will begin implementing and keep you updated. Question - doesn't the Category model need to have 'has many :categoricals?

Comment: Correct! I missed that part. Edited the answer :)

Comment: awesome :) does the Categorical model need to have a table as well?

Comment: Yes, a table is needed for `categoricals` with columns `category_id`, `categorizable_id and` `categorizable_type`

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Happy coding ;)

Comment: What columns does your Category table have?

Comment: Just the `name` column, if you are using the gem `acts_as_tree` then you need to add `parent_id` as well.

Comment: how would you add_to_category from a view? with '= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select Category' ?

Comment: @AbhishekSarkar What type of columns are the categoricals?