# Creating an ActiveRecord Relation of parent instances with specific child instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I made categories using [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762933/6079623) as a guide. I set categories as a resource in my routes, and used this to query the specific `Product` instances:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @products = []

    products = Product.all

    products.each do |product|
      if product.categories.include?(@category)
        @products << product
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then iterate over `@products` in my view. This has become a problem because I want `categories/show` to share a view with `products/index` to be more DRY. `products/index` just uses `<%= render @products %>`, and I can't pass `render` an array.

How can I query products with specific categories?

Pseudo-ish code of what I had in mind:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.where(categories.include?(@category))
  end
end
```

Category setup from comment:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree order: :name
  has_many :categoricals
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
end

class Categorical < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true

  validates_presence_of :category, :categorizable
end

module Categorizable 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :categoricals, as: :categorizable
    has_many :categories, through: :categoricals
  end

  def add_to_category(category)
    self.categoricals.create(category: category)
  end

  def remove_from_category(category)
    self.categoricals.find_by(category: category).maybe.destroy
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Categorizable
end

p = Product.find(1000) # returns a product, Ferrari
c = Category.find_by(name: 'car') # returns the category car

p.add_to_category(c) # associate each other
p.categories # will return all the categories the product belongs to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your main question:

> How can I query products with specific categories?

`Product.includes(:categories).where(categories: {id: params[:id]}).references(:categories)`

Check out this link for more info on preloading associations: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/